# Cannot convert string to Type (enum) c#

Tags: c#, string, enums, converters

I am messing around with a source for a game I play, and I'm making an in game command, but I've ran into a problem.

```
public enum WeatherType
{
    None = 1,
    Rain = 2,
    Snow = 3,
    RainWind = 4,
    AutumnLeaves = 5,
    CherryBlossomPetals = 7,
    CherryBlossomPetalsWind = 8,
    BlowingCotten = 9,
    Atoms = 10
}
```

`GC.MyClient.SendPacket(General.MyPackets.Weather(Splitter[1], Convert.ToUInt32(Splitter[2]), Convert.ToUInt32(Splitter[3]), Convert.ToUInt32(Splitter[4])));`

The error is on Splitter[1], it says "cannot convert string to WeatherType".
Does anyone know how to fix this? Cause I'm really stumped. Thanks

Comment: You have to Type cast it to `WeatherType` in this case.

Comment: It may be helpful to show us what `Splitter` contains, and what `General.MyPackets.Weather` expects/does

Answer (score 0):

Like you did in all the cases

add this to your code and it will work for you

```
Convert.ToUInt32(Splitter[1])
```